"Type character does not declare data type" error
I am trying to view an image in a picturebox from a stored path in a SQL Server table column. I am getting error messages:

Type character '& does not declare data type 'String'
comma, ')" or a valid expression continuation expected
')' expected

I searched YouTube and had no luck.

Table Data
Column Path

Form Info
TextBox - txtpicPath
PictureBox - PicBox1

Code to load is
Private Sub Showimage1()
    If Con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Con.Close()

    End If
    Con.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Path from Data where id = '" & TxtPicPath.Text&"'"
    Dim img As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        Dim pathstring As String = Path.Combine(img)
        PicBoxStaff.Image = Image.FromFile(pathstring)

        Con.Close()
End Sub

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Rather than calling Image.FromFile and assigning the result to the Image property of your PictureBox, just assign the file path to the ImageLocation property.

Why are you calling Path.Combine and only passing as single partial path? What do you think comb9ingi9ng one value does?

Literal type characters can be useful when initialising variables. Docs: Type characters (Visual Basic). Knowing about them, you will be able to interpret the error message next time.

@jmcilhinney, how do I assigning the result to the Image property of your PictureBox, just assign the file path to the ImageLocation property.

I hope you don't really need to be told how to assign a value to a property.

Missread your response

You have lost spaces near the second & and parenthesis at the end in the line
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Path from Data where id = '" & TxtPicPath.Text&"'"

It should be
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Path from Data where id = '" & TxtPicPath.Text & "'")

With the space missing, you have accidentally used a deprecated VB.NET feature called "Type characters": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters

Thank you so much, I was looking at it for so long, i just missed the simple fix.

@Kevin, I would recommend not using explicit concatenation in this and most other situations anyway. String interpolation is more readable and less error-prone: Dim cmd As New SqlCommand($"Select Path from Data where id = '{TxtPicPath.Text}'"). Personallyk, I pretty much never use more than one & operator in a single statement. If more would be required, string interpolation is probably a better option.

This is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks

@jmcilhinney, I learn most of what I do from you tube, I follow what they do, then try and understand why they do it later on. It's about the only way I can teach myself
